# Normalizing a wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, normalization

> A particle with mass $m$ is moving in one dimension. The wave function of the particle is
>
> $$\Psi(x,t)=Axe^{-(\sqrt{km}/2\hbar)x^2}e^{-i\sqrt{k/m}(3/2)t}$$
>
> for $-\infty<x<\infty$, where $k$ and $A$ are constants. Normalize this wave function.

To normalize a wave function, we impose the condition $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\Psi(x,t)|^2\mathrm{d}x=1$$ and solve for any constants (in this case, $A$, and possibly $k$). To make my life easier, I set $D=\frac{\sqrt{km}}{\hbar}$, so $\Psi(x,t)=Axe^{-(D/2)x^2}e^{-i\sqrt{k/m}(3/2)t}$, and $|\Psi(x,t)|^2=A^2x^2e^{-Dx^2}$. Thus, we are tasked with evaluating the integral $$A^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-Dx^2}\mathrm{d}x$$

Using an integral table (http://integral-table.com/), I found that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2e^{-Dx^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{D^3}}\mathrm{erf}(x\sqrt{D})\bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\frac{x}{2D}e^{-Dx^2}\bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$

Supposedly ([https://www.eng.tau.ac.il/~yosish/courses/vlsi1/I-6-diffusion.pdf](https://www.eng.tau.ac.il/%7Eyosish/courses/vlsi1/I-6-diffusion.pdf)), $\mathrm{erf}(\infty)=1$ and $\mathrm{erf}(-\infty)=-1$, so the first term evaluates to $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{D^3}}$. For the second term, since $D$ is a positive quantity, evaluating it at $\infty$ gives $0$, but I can't seem to use similar reasoning and intuition for $-\infty$.

Crudely substituting $-\infty$ into the expression gives $(-\infty)(e^\infty)=(-\infty)(\infty)$. Is this an indeterminate form? And if so, how should L'Hospital's rule be used to help? I tried it a few different ways and didn't make any progress.

PS: It might be silly to want to do the last step of evaluating the integral at its limits, when I already used a table to get to that step, but I'm mostly just curious to see how it can be done analytically / algebraically.

Comment: Guess you've not seen Gaussian integrals before?

Comment: Not really, the only one I've seen is for e^{-x^2} over the whole real line.

Comment: Well think about this: $-\frac{d}{dD}e^{-Dx^2}=x^2e^{-Dx^2}$, no?

Comment: Crudely substituting $-\infty$ for $x$ in the $-x^2$ in the exponent gives you $+\infty$? Check your signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut it short, the integral you need is (assuming $\alpha>0$): $$\underset{-\infty }{\overset{\infty }{\int }}{x}^{2}{e}^{-\alpha {x}^{2}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{{\alpha }^{3}}}$$
As suggested in the comments, it's one of the [gaussian integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). The mistake you made is a purely algebraic one, since you inserted $-\infty$ into $e^{-x^2}$ and got $e^{+\infty}$ instead of $e^{-\infty}$, which properly extinguishes the associated divergent term.